# Factorial list in python 3 not running

Tags: python, factorial

I'm still a beginner so please bear with me. So I'm trying to get a list of factorial numbers from 1 to 5.

```
factorial=[]
for i in range(1,5):
    for x in range(1,5):
        while(i>x):
            factorial.append(i*x)
```

When I switch out the factorial.append for print it just continously spits out 2s, does anyone know why, and if so what to do to fix this and what other viable method is there to get a list of factorial numbers?

Comment: You have an infinite loop, you never update `i` or `x` once you're inside the `while` loop

Comment: You have to add a condition to exit from de while

Comment: The best debugger is to take a piece of paper and start executing the program yourself in the paper. You will immediately see why it doesn't work and find the appropriate solution.

Comment: About the second question, if you have the factorial of n, then calculating the factorial of n+1 is trivial. No need of nested loops or recalculations.

Answer (score 1):

I this case, I recommend you to use a recursive function:

```
def factorial(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return x*factorial(x-1)
```

Ex:

```
>>>factorial(5)
120
>>>factorial(10)
3628800
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like :

```
>>> f=[1]  # initialized your list 
>>> for i in range(5):  # take each value in the list [0,1,2,3,4] 
...     f.append(f[i]*(i+1)) #to create a next point multiply with the last value
... 
>>> f=f[1:] #don't keep the first (repeated) point
>>> f #you have your list !
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting stuck in your `while` loop.
If you go step by step through your code, you'll see what is going on:
In the first loop, `i` value will be 1, and `x` values from 1 to 5, so `i` will never be > than `x`, thus you won't enter the while loop.
At the start of the second loop, `i` value will be 2 and `x` value will be 1, so you will enter the `while` loop.
You will stay in stay in the `while` loop until `i` becomes lower or equal to `x`, but this will never happen because to continue with the `for` loop you'll need to exit the `while` loop first.

Despite the error, i do not understand the reasoning that brought you there.
The common way to handle factorials is with recursion, as @Julio CamPlaz's answer shows, but it may simplier to understand the following:

```
# in each for loop, you multiply your n variable for the i value
# and you store the result of the moltiplication in your n variable
n=1
for i in range(1,6): # if you want the numbers from 1 to 5, you have to increase by one your maximum value
    n = n*i

print n
```